# Apache Superset - Problems with the display of shapefile data

Tags: geometry, polygon

I have added a shapefile file in my PostgreSQL and this is how it looks visually.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRSWz.png

The same shapefile I added in Superset Apache from the PostgreSQL database and then if I take the visualization DECK.GL PATH and then take the column with the Geometry (polyline as lines encoding) it looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlKC2.png